# Referencing js and css and getting Filenotfoundexception

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, relative-path, realpath

the relative  JS and CSS path mentioned in my JSP is not being picked up instead its giving some archive path from war file throwing file not found exception.

could it be because of the entry in my weblogic.xml (version 12c )

```
 "<wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled/> true <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled/>"
```

though I am not using real path in JSP.

its only being used in java class `( absoluteDiskPath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath(path) )`to refer a static file.

also  Any workaround to fetch real path.

Comment: Does it work with absolute path?

Comment: we want to deploy on server so need relative path. It works with absolute path on LOCAL. The jsp's were picking relative path in all ( DEV/ UAT) environments on the server till date with this change, suddenly on one env , this issue came and logs indicated Filenotfoundexception for css and js ,files for which path was not found indicated, path of js and css from archived path and war file and not of reference path.